# I want to show kernel page table

Tags: kernel, filesystem, compiling

Firist, I install ubuntu on my labtop.(LG Gram model)

I downloaded kernel source, version 6.0

I also make sure about config.

CONFIG_GENERIC_PTDUMP=y
CONFIG_PTDUMP_CORE=y
CONFIG_PTDUMP_DEBUGFS=y

Then, I use make config to enable PTDUMP_DEBUGFS.
(kernel hacking à memory debugging à export kernel page table...)

After I build kernel and reboot,
use mount –t debugfs /.
And then, I want to show kernel page_table,
which will be included on sys/kernel/debug/

But I can't see kernel_page_table on it.
Even I build again and again, I can't show it.

So, there is some idea about what I missed.

1->something wrong in mount.

2->In this version, kernel_page_table is included other directory

3->(just problem about my knowlege???)

Is there anyone who can fix it??